# Sheafification: Show that $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}=\mathscr{F}_x$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My today's question is about a proof of [this book](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf). More precisely we are talking about the proof of Prop. 2.24 on page 52. The book says that we have $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}=\mathscr{F}_x$ for all $x\in X$. I tried to verify that but unfolding the definition of elements of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}$ is very technical. So I got stuck. Furthermore, it can't be meant literally because elements of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}$ and $\mathscr{F}_x$ aren't of the same type so to speak. So what is meant by that equality?

Here my approach to unfold the definition of elements of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}$:

An element of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}$ is the equivalence class of a pair $(U,(s_y)_{y\in U})$ with $x\in U$. Each pair $(U',(s'_y)_{y\in U'})$ is equivalent to $(U,(s_y)_{y\in U})$ iff there is a $V\subseteq U\cap U'$ with $x\in V$ and $(s_y)_{y\in U}|_V=(s'_y)_{y\in U'}|_V$. By definition of the restriction that means for all $y\in V$ we have $s_y=s'_y$. Now the equality $s_y=s'_y$ could be itself unfold in a similar way since $s_y$ is again an equivalence class of pairs.

Is it correct what I did so far and does it help me to show $\tilde{\mathscr{F}_x}=\mathscr{F}_x$?

Comment: First, the "equality" means "canonically isomorphic." So you should be looking for a canonical map from one side to the other. The sheafification $\tilde{\mathscr{F}}$ comes equipped with a map $\mathscr{F}\to\tilde{\mathscr{F}}$ of presheaves. Any such map induces a map on stalks at each $x\in X$. Can you verify that this particular map is an isomorphism?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Just as a matter of interest the map you suggest when taken as $\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow\tilde{\mathcal{F}}(U)$ need be neither surjective nor injective right ?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: Let me write down what the induced map on stalks does. Let $s_x\in \mathscr{F}_x$. So there is a $U$ with $x\in U$ and an $s\in\mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $s_x$ is the germ of $s$ in $x$. The image of $s_x$ is now $((s_y)_{y\in U})_x$. Correct so far?

Comment: Dear @Rene, That's correct.

Comment: Dear @principal-ideal-domain, Right. Lift the stalk $s_x\in\mathscr{F}_x$ to a section $s\in\mathscr{F}(U)$ over some open around $x$. Take its image under $\mathscr{F}(U)\to\tilde{\mathscr{F}}(U)$, which is $((s_y)_{y\in U})$. This section of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}}$ over $U$ represents the stalk in $\tilde{\mathscr{F}}_x$ which is the image of $s_x$ under the map in question. Given another stalk $t_x$, which you can assume lifts to a section $t\in\mathscr{F}(U)$, possibly after shrinking $U$, what if $((s_y)_y)$ and $((t_y)_y)$ have the same stalk at $x$? It means they agree after restriction

Comment: to some open $V\subseteq U$ containing $x$. But these restrictions are just $((s_y)_{y\in V})$ and $((t_y)_{y\in V})$. So, in particular, $s_x=t_x$. Can you prove surjectivity?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell I think, I got it. Thanks for your proof of injectivity. For surjectivity let $x\in U$ and $(s_y)_{y\in U}\in \tilde{\mathscr{F}}(U)$. Now I have to find a preimage of the germ of $(s_y)_{y\in U}$ in $x$. By definition of $\tilde{\mathscr{F}}(U)$ there is an open $W\subseteq U$ with $x\in W$ and a $t\in\mathscr{F}(W)$ with $t_w=s_w$ for all $w\in W$. I claim that the image of $t_x$ is the germ of $(s_y)_{y\in U}$ in $x$. Indeed the restriction of $(s_y)_{y\in U}$ to $W$ is $(t_y)_{y\in W}$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are getting at but if you have 
$$s_x\in \mathcal{F}_x=\lim\mathcal{F}(U)$$ then there is some $U$ and $t\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $t$ restricts to $s_x$. So the equivalalence class of the germ $U, (t_y)$ about the point $x$ will be $s_x$.